# Javascript's getTimezoneOffset returns wrong offset?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, timezone-offset

My computer's timezone is GMT-7:00 Mountain time US & Canada. I tried a javascript example on w3cschool:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var d=new Date()
var gmtHours = -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
document.write("The local time zone is: GMT " + gmtHours);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The result is: The local time zone is: GMT -6

Why does this function return an offset with 1 hour difference from the actual timezone on my machine?

Comment: Daylight savings time? pure guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently in [Mountain Daylight Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_Daylight_Time).

Let's think about another similar scenario.
If your friend open on Android smartphone, is there any variable?

Can it return 0 if a user disables Javascript on Android or when he
installed VPN app or other privacy Android app?

What does it mean 0 from new Date().getTimezoneOffset()?
Is the user telling he is living in Australia a real liar?
Or it can be from other programmatic blocking?